# How to use multiple parenthesis properly in a batch file

Tags: file, batch-file

Here is this batch im makeing

```
@echo off  
title TXTanimation  
set dir101=C:\USers\%username%\Desktop\file.bat  
goto menu  
echo Lets make a text animation  
pause  
set /p dir101=where will the .bat be saved:  
echo @ECHO OFF > %dir101%  
:menu  
echo 0=Edit important information  
echo 1=Display .txt  
echo 2=Play sound  
echo 3=Close sound player  
echo 4=Add nessicary wait between .txt  
echo 5=Label point  
echo 6=Edit variable  
echo 7=Goto point  
echo 8=Create IF sentence  
echo 9=End it  
Set /p choose=which one:  
  
If '%choose%'=='0' (  
SEt /p title=What is the title  
:LOL101  
set /p color=what color do you want (type test to experiment with the colors)  
If '%color%'=='test' goto tester  
goto model  
:tester  
SEt /p test=Please give hexadecimal number type exit to leave:  
if '%test%'=='exit' goto LOL101  
color %test%  
goto tester  
:model 
echo title %title% >> %dir101%  
echo color %color% >> %dir101%  
)  
  
If '%choose%'=='1' (  
set /p dir=what is the dir of your .txt:  
)  
If '%choose%'=='1' (  
echo cls >> %dir101%  
echo type %dir% >> %dir101%  
)  
If '%choose%'=='4' (  
SEt /p thyme=How much milliseconds 250 is usual:  
echo ping 192.168.1.1 -n 1 -w %thyme% >> %dir101%  
)  
goto menu  
If '%choose%'=='9' (  
echo Thanks for making  
pause  
)
```

Its going to be used to create .txt animations in a .bat file. I can finish it but I first need to fix a problem.

The problem is that it does
`echo title %title% >> %dir101% echo color %color% >> %dir101%`
Even though there in parenthesis. Going forward, how can I refactor these parenthesis to get the outcome that I would like.

Comment: Silly question time, do single quotes work in a .bat file or in cmd at all? I've only ever seen double quotes.

Comment: @Bill It dosen't matter when it comes to IF statements

Comment: @JakeInc. are you saying the problem is that your code is executing `echo title %title% >> %dir101%` and `echo color %color% >> %dir101%` even when your choose doesn't have a value of '0'? As dbenham said, your actual question is kind of unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not very clear about what problem you are having. However, I see a common problem with your code.

You are setting environment variables and then attempting to access the value using immediate expansion, all within the same code block enclosed by parentheses. This cannot work because the expansion occurs when the block is parsed, and the entire block is parsed in one pass before anything is executed. So you end up getting the value that existed before the value is set within the block.

The solution is to enable delayed expansion using `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` at the top  of your script. Then use delayed expansion (`!var!`) instead of normal expansion (`%var%`) to get the value of the variable at execution time instead of at parse time.

For more information, type `HELP SET` at the command prompt and begin reading at the paragraph that begins *"Finally, support for delayed environment variable expansion has been added..."*